# Bush error. Can't open the GUI support

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

I upgraded my 18.04 LTS Ubuntu using `sudo apt upgrade`. It needed to upgrade about 1500 packages and took so long that I left it upgrade overnight.

The next day, I checked on it and the upgrade was completed, but the terminal icon had turned bluish. I switched the system off and the next time I powered it on, it only had a black screen without the GUI display. I couldn't open Firefox or any other application, like Sublime Text.

Now, I can navigate using the GRUB loader only. I had previously  installed some Linux repositories and also `katoolin` separately.

What might be the problem?

Comment: I’d be inclined to try the Boot Repair Disk first. It’s available on SourceForge, a google search will provide a link. Then you need to make a live disk/usb and boot it. There is some Ubuntu documentation about it here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows - together with the command line alternative. If you have an Ubuntu live disk/usb you can install the Boot Repair Disk temporarily in the live session. The link describes a graphical way to do this.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! _“I had previously installed some Linux repositories and also katoolin separately.”_ This sentence means a lot of ambiguity. Please [edit] your question to clarify it. What does “separately” mean? You should not `apt upgrade` Ubuntu with Kali (katoolin) repositories, see https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin#warning. Also what do you mean by “navigate using the GRUB loader”? Can you boot Ubuntu? What happens?